# Sending email from directly within Zoho Projects task

Tags: email, zoho

Zoho Projects is fantastic and I am currently exploring its potential.

One of its strong points is its task management, which can be reported across projects, assigned to any user oftheprojects and given lots of details, attachments, etc.

In my case however, many of my tasks involve sending a client an email.It is inconvenient for me to see the task, the. Go to my email, send the email. And then go back to task and mark done, every time I need to repeattheprocess - which is often. Also, having the emails separate from the actual task means that I cannot actually view the correspondence within the task.

My question is, do any Zoho eerts or developers familiar with the Zoho API know of any way to configure Zoho tasks to allow you to send email directly from inside a task? I know that can already email to a task, but can you set something up to allow you to email FROM a task?